# Django Rest Framework - Request.user is Always AnonymousUser and request.POST is empty

Tags: angularjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm facing an issue with my Authentication/Login View. This system was working before but i recently switched to a new server and can't get it fixed.

When attempting to login via the auth view the request.user is always an AnonymousUser as if i didn't feed in any auth credentials. I've tried logging the request.POST but it seems to be an empty dict.

I have a traceback here:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://45.55.149.3:8000/api/auth/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'webapp',
 'rest_framework',
 'djrill')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  456.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  453.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/appointments-app/appointments/webapp/views.py" in post
  40.         login(request, request.user)
File "/home/appointments-app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  111.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/auth/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here i have the API auth view which is failing:

```
class AuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (QuietBasicAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        login(request, request.user)
        return Response(OldUserSerializer(request.user).data)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return Response({})
```

below is the authentication class that i'm using:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication

class QuietBasicAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    # disclaimer: once the user is logged in, this should NOT be used as a
    # substitute for SessionAuthentication, which uses the django session cookie,
    # rather it can check credentials before a session cookie has been granted.
    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'xBasic realm="%s"' % self.www_authenticate_realm
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Usually, you would use information in the request to fetch a user, then call `login(request, user)` to log them in. Calling `login(request, request.user)` doesn't make sense - if `request.user` wasn't anonymous, there would be no need to log them in.

Comment: @Alasdair it seems that i can't access the credentials submitted in the Ajax request. as i said request.POST seems to be empty, request.user does not container them either, nor does request.username or request.password for example which are the keys i submitted in the request.

Comment: What are the contents of `request.body`?

Comment: @Alasdair the request.body is empty

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Django REST framework's authentication classes, you do not need to log in the user. The user will be authenticated by Django REST framework ahead of time, and the credentials will be validated in the process.

Right now by calling `login` you are trying to log in the current user (`request.user`) and associate them with the current request (`request`). DRF will do this automatically for you, and `request.user` will contain a `User` instance if it was able to authenticate the user and an `AnonymousUser` (what you are seeing) if it is not able to.

If you are trying to log in the user for the Django request (not the DRF request, [which is different](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)) you need to reference the Django request which is stored as `request._request`.

```
login(request._request, request.user)
```